# MVC - pass all ListBox items back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, listbox

I created a database with the Entity Framework with the model first approach. Among other things, I have a type `ContentEntry` and a type `Tag`. Every `ContentEntry` can have multiple `Tag`s and every `Tag` can be used by multiple `ContentEntry`’s. It should be such that no tag exists twice in the db, for that is the n:m relation:
[image: Image of the realtion between Tag and ContentEntry]

Now, I try to create a controller/view to create a new `ContentEntry` with `Tag`s. I have no idea how to create a ListBox which give **all** his items back to the controller. The JavaScript (with jQuery) is no problem for me:

```
<span class="label">Tags</span>
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Tags, 
                 new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags),
                 new { id = "lbTags" })

<input type="text" id="tbTag" />
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTag();" />
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="delTags();" />

<script>
    function addTag() {
        $('#lbTags').append($('<option>',
            { value: $("#tbTag").val(), text: $("#tbTag").val() }));
    }
    function delTags() {
        $("#lbTags option:selected").remove();
    }
</script>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags, "", new { @class = "input-error" })
```

But my `Tags` collection stays always empty:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateBlogEntry
  ([Bind(Include = "Id,Published,Title,AccountId,HtmlContent,Tags")]BlogEntry blogEntry)
{
    //blogEntry.Tags is always empty
    if (ModelState.IsValid
    {
        db.ContentEntrySet.Add(blogEntry);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

`BlogEntry` is a derivate of `ContentEntry` and `ContentEntry.Tags` is a `ICollection<Tag>`.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this task?

**EDIT**:
Here is my GET-method for CreateBlogEntry:

```
public ActionResult CreateBlogEntry()
{
    //ViewBag.Tags = db.TagSet;
    return View(new BlogEntry()
    {
        Published = DateTime.Now,
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `GET` method for `CreateBlogEntry` ?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I added the GET method to my question

Comment: One way to fix this problem is to create a viewmodel that will have all of the attributes you need from both tables

Comment: You need to show your models, but it would appear that your model has a property named `Tags` which is a complex object. You cannot bind a `<select>` (or any control) to a complex object. You need a view model with a property (say `int[] SelectedTags`) and then `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, new SelectList(Model.Tags, "Id", "Name")` assuming you want to display the tag name and bind to the tag Id's.

Comment: Note that no javascript is required, and in you case it would not do anything since you have not given the input with `id="tbTag"` a `name` attribute so nothing would post back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default model binder will bind the selected values from the multiselect to a collection.

Change your view to

```
 @Html.ListBox("SelectedTags"
 , new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags,"Name","Name")
 , new { id = "lbTags" })
```

This way even if you load the values from server it will work. Notice that I am not using the `ListBoxFor` because I want to set the name of the collection.

Your `BlogEntry` model that comes into `CreateBlogEntry` method will have a property like below

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTags{ get; set; }
```

You can then make use of this `SelectedTags` property and create a new model that goes into you database.

If you don't want this behavior, your will have to override the default model binder's behavior. You can find all about the binders [in this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).I will try to update the answer with model binder but this is enough to unblock you in the mean time.

One other note, you are using all the properties `BlogEntry` the bind is unnecessary. You can remove it.

**Update - The custom model binder version**

You can create your own binder like below:

```
public class FancyBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext
   ,ModelBindingContext bindingContext
   ,Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.Name == "BlogEntry")
        {
            return BindBlogEntry(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
        }
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }

    private static object BindBlogEntry(ControllerContext controllerContext
   ,ModelBindingContext bindingContext
   ,Type modelType)
    {
        var tagsOnForm = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Tags"];
        return new BlogEntry
        {
            Content = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Content"],
            Tags = GetTags(tagsOnForm)
        };
    }

    private static List<Tag> GetTags(string tagsOnForm)
    {
        var tags = new List<Tag>();
        if (tagsOnForm == null)
            return tags;

        tagsOnForm.Split(',').ForEach(t=>tags.Add(new Tag {Name = t}));
        return tags;
    }
}
```

You can wire up this binder in the global.asax like below:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new FancyBinder();
    }
}
```

I hope this is clear enough. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It is pretty late in Germany, so I will test your custom model binder solution in some hours. 
But your first idea works nearly perfect - thank you!

Comment: I testet your FancyBinder yet and it works also great. But I think it is more easier for me to create a second model.